# how to get number of files modified in a folder month wise

Tags: php

how to get number of files modified in a folder month wise

I have a folder containing audio clips , i want to make report of files month wise with year uploaded or updated in that folder

```
$dir="uploads/audio/";
$result=get_files_report_monthly($dir); 
foreach( $result as $key=>$val )
{ 
$time = date("Y/m",filemtime($val));
echo "<br/>";
echo $filesize  = filesize($val);
echo "<br/>";
clearstatcache();

}
```

**Function I am calling**

```
function get_files_report_monthly($directory, $result = array())
{
$directory = realpath($directory);
$directory_content = glob($directory.'/*');
foreach($directory_content as $item) {
if(is_dir($item)) {
$result = get_updated_files($item, $result);
} elseif(strtotime($date) < filemtime($item)) {
$result[] = $item;
}
}
return $result;
}
```

**Output**

```
2018/10
384340
2018/10
384340
2018/10
384340
2018/10
384340
2018/10
384340
2018/10
384340

Desire Out is as 

Month    -    Files -      Size 

2016-Jan     38          999999999

2016-Feb     99          999999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have made some changes to your existing code, it should work.

```
$result = get_files_report_monthly($dir); 
foreach( $result as $key=>$val )
{ 
    echo $key.' '.$val['count'].' '.$val['size'];
    echo "<br>";
}

function get_files_report_monthly($directory, $result = array())
{
    $directory = realpath($directory);
    $directory_content = glob($directory.'/*');
    foreach($directory_content as $item) {
        $modified_time  =   filemtime($item);
        $modified_at    =   date('Y-M',$modified_time);
        if(isset($result[$modified_at])){
            $result[$modified_at]['count']  =   $result[$modified_at]['count'] + 1;
            $result[$modified_at]['size']   =   $result[$modified_at]['size'] + filesize($item);
        }
        else{
            $result[$modified_at]['count']  =   1;
            $result[$modified_at]['size']   =   filesize($item);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: may you please check its not reporting accurate result , there are 3 files only in feb 2017 but its displaying 10

Comment: #v Hansda , the above code is working fine , it was filezilla issue , filezilla displays only 9998 files , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code be helpfull

```
foreach(get_files_report_monthly(__DIR__) as $key=>$month) {
   printf("%s %d %d",$key, $month['count'], $month['size']); 
}

function get_files_report_monthly($dir)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
        if ($file->isFile()) {
            $month = date('Y-M', $file->getMTime());
            switch (isset($result[$month])) {
                case true:
                    $result[$month]['count'] += 1;
                    $result[$month]['size'] += $file->getSize();
                    break;
                case false:
                    $result[$month]['count'] = 1;
                    $result[$month]['size'] = $file->getSize();
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```